# With what speed does the particle leave the magnetic field given its circular path radius?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, magnetic-fields

I've attached the question as an image below as it's a graphical question.

It simply states:

> Different magnetic fields are present in the two chambers shown. A particle enters the first chamber at a velocity of $80$m/s and is deflected into a circular path of radius $200$mm. In the second chamber it follows a circular path of radius $100$mm.  ***At what speed does the
> particle leave the second chamber?***

[image: Magnetic fields speed in circular path question]

Using the equation $r = \frac{mv}{Bq}$ we can see that the radius is proportional to the velocity.

As the particle's circular path radius is $200$mm, its velocity is $80$m/s.  So when the path radius is $100$mm (half radius), wouldn't its velocity be also half? So the velocity would be $40$m/s when it leaves the second chamber.

However, the answer is $80$m/s. I don't understand why this is the answer.

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recall that the magnetic force $\mathbf{F}=q \mathbf{v}\times \mathbf{B}$ is by definition perpendicular to the velocity of the particle (hence the circular trajectories), so the work done by it is zero. This means that the particle's kinetic energy is conserved through the motion, i.e. its speed is constant.

In your problem, the second circular trajectory has smaller radius because there is a stronger magnetic field in that chamber.

Comment: Ah, yes, I recall that no work is done for that reason and so speed is constant. But how do we know the field strength is greater in the second chamber? I understand that given the speed is constant, it must be greater, but if that's the case, why is velocity in the equation r=mv/Bq? Thank you!

Comment: I think I don't understand the question, but given that equation, if we know the speed is constant (and of course assuming the mass and charge doesn't change) then the only possible way to reduce the radius is to increase the field by the same factor.

Comment: So what you're saying is given a particle moves in circular motion with a given velocity, assuming no resistance forces act on the particle to slow it down, inside a magnetic field the particle will ALWAYS move at the same velocity? Sorry for the confusing question.
If not, in what case would velocity change in this circumstance? If the magnetic field strength was the same in both chambers and the particle was the same (i.e. same mass and charge) and radius decreased, wouldn't velocity have to decrease?

Comment: It will always move with the same speed since it moves in a circular motion, driven by a perpendicular force to the motion at all times (a caveat is that charged accelerated particles radiate away energy so it would loss a bit of kinetic energy- but that's a minor correction here). For your last question: ask yourself, why would the radius decrease in that situation? The particle has no reasons to change its motion in that case! It only feels a constant magnetic force so if left free the radius of its motion would be constant too.

Comment: Right, ok, got it! Thank you so so much for answering all my questions, this has given me a much better understanding :)

Answer (score 0):

The answer is (C) since the magnetic field changes and the radius changes therefore we must assume the velocity is unchanged because elsewise: if the velocity halved due to the radius halving we  are assuming the magnetic field is constant between two chambers – but it is not, as stated in the question so inference – it remains same